# Google Places API display places photo on recyclerview

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, android-glide

I am fetching places data from google places API and it returns 20 results at a time. And I am displaying data into recyclerview. So what will be best approach to display all 20 places image in recyclerview without exceeding google api's daily quota.

I have tried this but it didn't work, and I can't figure it why it is not working.

```
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference="
                    + places.getPhotoRefrence() + "&sensor=true&key=" + key;

Glide.with(context)
                    .load(url)
                    .into(holder.placeListIV);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your adapter class below `onBindViewHolder()` method implement this

```
/**
* Fetching photos of places using placeId and setting photos on imageview of recyclerview
     */
    if (!places.getPhotoRefrence().equals("null")) {
        String photorefrence = places.getPhotoRefrence();
        String url = baseUrl + photorefrence + "&key=" + key;


        final String placeId = places.getPlaceId();
        final Task<PlacePhotoMetadataResponse> photoMetadataResponse = mGeoDataClient.getPlacePhotos(placeId);
        photoMetadataResponse.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlacePhotoMetadataResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlacePhotoMetadataResponse> task) {
                // Get the list of photos.
                PlacePhotoMetadataResponse photos = task.getResult();
                // Get the PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer (metadata for all of the photos).
                PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer photoMetadataBuffer = photos.getPhotoMetadata();
                // Get the first photo in the list.
                PlacePhotoMetadata photoMetadata = photoMetadataBuffer.get(0);
                // Get the attribution text.
                CharSequence attribution = photoMetadata.getAttributions();
                // Get a full-size bitmap for the photo.
                Task<PlacePhotoResponse> photoResponse = mGeoDataClient.getPhoto(photoMetadata);
                photoResponse.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlacePhotoResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlacePhotoResponse> task) {
                        PlacePhotoResponse photo = task.getResult();
                        Bitmap bitmap = photo.getBitmap();
                        holder.placeListIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

And don't forget to initialize `mGeoDataClient`.

mGeoDataClient = com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places.getGeoDataClient(this, null);

If you need more help then click [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/photos) or you can comment, I will do my best to help you out.

Comment: wow this amazingly works. Thank you for helping and sharing this code.

Comment: feel free to ask questions Stackoverflow is great community helping developer like us. And glad it did worked for you.

Comment: We should put downloaded images in cache to avoId downloading them each time

Comment: If I knew that I would have told him, so could please share idea how to cache downloaded images from google places API and use images from cache.

Comment: This works great for me. I was overthinking the solution by using AsyncTask